# Python + OTR using otrxmppchannel, unable to send message

Tags: python, off-the-record-messaging

Can anyone help me send a message with OTR encryption with Python?

I have tried the instructions from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/OTRXMPPChannel/1.0.4) without success.

My program until now is:

```
import os
import time
from otrxmppchannel import OTRXMPPChannel

privkey = open('mykey.otrprivkey', 'r').read()

channel = OTRXMPPChannel('sender@jappix.com','password_of_sender','recepient@blabla.com',privkey)

channel.send('')  # Force OTR setup
time.sleep(3)  # Wait a bit for OTR setup to complete
channel.send('This message should be encrypted')
```

And the file mykey.otrprivkey is a file that includes the private key, which has the form:

```
AAAA.............X3cE=
```

As a key file I have tried files with the form:

```
(privkeys
 (account
(name "senderv@jappix.com")
(protocol prpl-jabber)
(private-key 
 (dsa 
  (p ....
```

but that doesn't work.